# I want to make a function that takes a list and returns the same list but without the duplicate elements, what's wrong with this program?

Tags: python, list, function

I want to make a function that takes a list and returns the same list but without the duplicate elements

```
def func(list1):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        list2 = [x for x in list1 if x != list1[i]]
        if list1[i] in list2:
            list1.remove(i)
            return list1
        

mylist = [1,2,3,4]
func(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of answers already showing how to implement this task correctly, but none discuss your actual code.

#### Deconstructing your code

Hopefully this will help understand why your code did not work. Here's your code, with comments added:

```
def func(list1):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        list2 = [x for x in list1 if x != list1[i]]
```

Here you construct a list, `list2`, that does not contain `list1[i]`.

```
        if list1[i] in list2:
```

This `if` statement is always going to be false, by construction of `list2`.

```
            list1.remove(i)
```

Even if you fix the logic of the `if` statement, `list1.remove(i)` would cause trouble: trying to remove elements of a list while iterating over it invalidates the indices for the rest of the iteration. It's best to avoid doing this and build the results into a new list instead.

Furthermore, `list1.remove(i)` is looking for value `i` in `list1` and will remove it, wherever it first finds it. It's not removing the i'th element, as this code seems to expect.

```
            return list1
```

And this return statement was probably not meant to be indented this deep, it should probablement have been at the same level as the `for` statement at the top.

#### Working code closer to your logic

While I don't think this is the best solution -- the other answers provide better ones -- here is a solution inspired from your code, which works.

```py
def func(list1):
    list2 = []  # We'll append elements here
    for item in list1:  # more pythonic way to loop over a list
        if item not in list2:
            list2.append(item)
    return list2
```

#### My preferred solution

OK, so now I'm duplicating information in other answers, but with Python 3.7(*) or more recent, where `dict` is guaranteed to keep the order of the elements inserted into it, I'd use @Pedro Maia's solution:

```py
def func(list1):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(list1))
```

In fact, I used that technique in my code base recently.

In older versions of Python, dicts are not ordered. However, there has been the [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class in the `collections` library since Python 2.7, so this code would work with any version of Python >= 2.7:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
def func(list1):
    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list1))
```

If you're not familiar with them, have a look at the [`collections` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) and the [`itertools` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), they provide immensely useful helpers for all sorts of problems.

(*) According to the manual for [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), Python `dict`s have only been guaranteed to be ordered since Python 3.7, even though they started actually being ordered in Python 3.6, at least for the CPython implementation. See also:  [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/3216427)

Answer (score 0):

Use a set:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,1,3,2,4]
mylist = set(mylist)
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

To keep the order you can do:

```
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))
```

which doesn't require any library

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
def remove_duplicates(l):
    return list(set(l))
```

Now `remove_duplicates([1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7])` will return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this input `l = [1,2,3,2,7,3,4,4,7,1]`

##### removing the duplicates without keeping order

use a python [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
list(set(l))
```

output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]`

##### keeping order

use a dictionary (or [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects))

```
from collections import Counter
list(Counter(l))
```

output: `[1, 2, 3, 7, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

In python we can use the set to remove the duplicate elements:

```py
def removeDuplicates(l):
    return list(set(l))


mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]

newList = removeDuplicates(mylist)

print(newList)
```